# Remove password protected profile from Mac with the terminal

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, expect

I have a password protected profile on my mac which I want to remove with the terminal. When running the command:

```
profiles -R -p MyProfile
```

The terminal asks me for the profile password:

```
Enter the profile removal password:
```

Now I have to type the password (no admin password) manually into the terminal. Is it possible to create a command which contains the password so that the profile is getting removed automatically?

Comment: Did you try separating them with a `;` or `&&`?

Comment: Yes, the terminal still asks for the password

Comment: You usually use expect in cases where you want to make interactive command non-interactive: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/expect/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man 1 profiles`,

```
-z  The profile removal password. If not specified and the profile requires
    a removal password, you will be prompted.
```

So I guess you need to make your command look like

```
profiles -R -p MyProfile -z MyProfilePassword
```